# Three divs next to eachother, content pushing others down

Tags: css, html, alignment

I've got three divs next to eachother and without content in them they align perfect.
However once I place another div inside the first one, the other 2 (middle and right) are pushed down. The inner div is smaller than his parent (the left one), so I don't see why it's pushing down.

This is the global wrapper:

```
.main-content {
    width: 1100px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

The left div:

```
.left-menu {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The middle:

```
.main {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And the right div:

```
.right-pane{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

At the moment they are classes rather than id's, but that shouldn't make a difference I guess?

Now once we place a div like the following inside left-menu the other 2 are pushed down:

```
<div class="leftmenu-item">
    <p class="redtext">This is a quite a long sentence hehehe</p>
    <p class="datetext">Date: 25-07-2013</p>
    <p class="timetext">Time: 13:00</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.leftmenu-item {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The other classes of the paragraphs only set a font type and a color.

So the whole structure looks like this:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="left-menu">
            <div class="leftmenu-item">
                         <p class="redtext">This is a quite a long sentence hehehe</p>
                         <p class="datetext">Date: 25-07-2013</p>
                         <p class="timetext">Time: 13:00</p>
                    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        Testy
    </div>

    <div class="right-pane">
        Hello.
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using float, but that is not working well either. If anyone knows a solution, i'd be happy

Comment: Better [fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) this.

Comment: add `vertical-align:top;` to those div.

Comment: Heh @avrahamcool that did the trick, please make a post so I can accept it

Comment: Ok, thanks. I opened a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align:top;` to those div.

By default they are aligned from their baseline.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a typo:

You have missed class selector for `main`

Comment: Oops, copy paste typo